# A potential bug involving Background Image and Media Query

Tags: tailwind-css

This current class works fine:

```
bg-[url('https://d2kcw0xpn7sann.cloudfront.net/[GLOBAL]/sellout-vbox-inner-bg.svg')]
```

But this one does not work:

```
lg:bg-[url('https://d2kcw0xpn7sann.cloudfront.net/[GLOBAL]/sellout-vbox-inner-bg.svg')]
```

Here is the tailwind play link if you wanna checkout for yourself

[enter link description here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Z7WRhCEcnm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about media query + background image but pattern. Try this

```html
<div class="h-64 w-64 md:bg-[url('https://picsum.photos/200/300')]"></div>
```

You'll see it working

This instead does not (image on hover)

```html
<div class="h-64 w-64 hover:bg-[url('https://d2kcw0xpn7sann.cloudfront.net/[GLOBAL]/sellout-vbox-inner-bg.svg')]"></div>
```

If you hover you class in TailwinPlay you should notice it is generates property but fail to generate class name

[image]

But if you replace `:` or one of brackets `[` with any symbol  it will generate class properly (of course image link will be broken in that case)

Why does this happen? I'm not entirely sure but I believe it because this image link meet Tailwind's pattern. Most common pattern for Tailwind's arbitrary values is

```html
variant:utility-[value]

e.g.

lg:bg-[red]

your case 
lg : bg- [ url(link) ]

lg - modifier
: - separator
bg- - utility
[] - arbitrary value wrapper
url(link) - arbitrary value
```

Also Tailwind supports variants combination e.g. `md:hover:[some]:`. If you look closer to your class `lg:bg-[url('https://d2kcw0xpn7sann.cloudfront.net/[GLOBAL]/sellout-vbox-inner-bg.svg')]` - it may be consider as two variants plus arbitrary value

```
lg: - variant 1
bg-[url('https: - variant 2
//d2kcw0xpn7sann.cloudfront.net/ - utility
[GLOBAL] - arbitrary value
```

So I think Tailwind confused here in a regex and don't know what to generate. Submit an issue in Tailwind's repository for that

Mean time if you need to fix it just [encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) square brackets

```html
lg:bg-[url('https://d2kcw0xpn7sann.cloudfront.net/%5BGLOBAL%5D/sellout-vbox-inner-bg.svg')]
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/prMNBbTHNs)